# Unregistering custom tinymce plugin?

Tags: functions, tinymce, child-theme

I want to unregister a custom tinymce plugin in one of my child themes. The custom tinymce plugin uses basically:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_plugins

excerpt:

```
add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", "foo_add_buttons" );
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'foo_register_buttons' );
```

What is the best way to remove this such that performance is the best? The two options I came up with are:

1. remove_filter("mce_external_plugins"); & remove_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'foo_register_buttons' );?
2. add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'disable_mce_buttons'); and simply remove the buttons that the parent theme adds?

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 was the only one that worked correctly.

```
function disable_mce_buttons($settings){

    $settings['external_plugins'] = '';
    $settings['toolbar3'] = '';
    return $settings;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'disable_mce_buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should work if you run the `remove_filter` on a hook.

```
function wpa_145664(){
  remove_filter("mce_external_plugins");
  remove_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'foo_register_buttons' );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'wpa_145664');
```